# UNC Path not working with blank space

Tags: c#, .net

I have a UNC path of `\\houtester\common\log library\graphics` that I'm needing to use in my c# program and obviously it won't won't because of that blank space.  How can I get this path to work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to use it, that is, with surrounding code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that the full path?
I'm assuming you may need \ prefixing your complete path. i.e:

```
string path = @"\\houtester\common\log library\graphics";
```

Also make sure that path is available from the machine you are attempting to connect from. Security settings could be botching you.

Comment: This will also work with appsettings as such: `@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UNCPath"].ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the literal string symbol '@' before the string `@"\\houtester\common\log library\graphics"`